# One problem on set theory having two parts

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Problem:

> Let $S$ be a universal set and $A$ be a fixed subset of $S$.
>
> - If $A\cup B = B$ holds for all subset $B$, prove that $A = \varnothing$,
> - If $A\cap B= B$ holds for all subset $B$, prove that $A =S$

What I have tried is the following

Let $x \in A$ then $x\in A\cup B \Rightarrow x\in B \Rightarrow A \subset B$.

Answer (score 2):

In the first case, consider $B = \emptyset$.  $A \cup \emptyset = \emptyset$ implies $A = \emptyset$.

- Note that $\emptyset \cup B = B$ holds for all $B$, so $ A = \emptyset $ is a good solution.

In the second case, consider $B = S$. $A \cap S = S$ implies $A = S$.

- Note that $S \cap B = B$ holds for all $B$, so $ A = S $ is a good solution.

Comment: @Joffan I shall have to prove, not to check the result. It is true that in the 1st case as I have proved that $A \subset B$ and it is true for all $B$, then one can consider $B=\phi$.

Comment: @user1942348 suggested a clarification to complete the proof.